# Can a function of the form $f(x) = x^n + x^{n+1} + c$ be symmetrical with respect to the $y$-axis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

Can a function over $\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(x)=f(-x)$ and be of the form:
$$f(x) = x^n + x^{n+1} + c$$
where $c$ can be anything except $c \neq -x^n -x^{n+1}$ or $c\neq -x^n$ nor $c\neq -x^{n+1}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n>1$, where $c$ is a function?

Comment: Typically $c$ means a constant value, but your last line shows as if it would be a function. Would you make it clear?

Comment: @peterh well a constant is also a function? But in this case the $c$ is a function.

Comment: Constant means a number, which is fix while you go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. A function is something what varies with it. If $c$ is here a function, it is an uncommon markup but possible; in this case your problem has a solution. If $c$ is a constant, then it is irrelevant.

Comment: @peterh Why does a function have to vary? Every constant can be written as a function $f(x)=c$?

Comment: Yes, actually giving a constant $c$ to a function $f(x)$ means that you give to $f(x)$ such a $c(x)$ function, for which $c(x)=c$ for all numbers. But, for example, your problem has only a solution if $c$ is a non-constant function.

Comment: @WaldoRozir Your statement that $c≠−x^n-x^{n+1}$ implies that $c$ may vary with x. As peterh mentions, conventionally $c$ means a constant (which wouldn′t vary with x). To get an answer you need to specify whether $r$ can vary with $x$.

Comment: @peterh can you give me the solution for $c$ is a non-constant? DonAntonio said there is no solution.

Comment: @user2460798 Ok next time I will take another letter. But can you give me an answer that differs from the case where $c$ is a constant? (btw. I also faced $c$ as a non-constant)

Comment: @WaldoRozir if $c=dx^n-x^{n-1}$ where $d\neq 1$ then the function becomes $f(x)=(d+1)x^n$ and is even if $n$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, do the math: for example, if $\;n\;$ is odd, then

$$x^n+x^{n+1}+c=f(x)=f(-x)=(-x)^n+(-x)^{n+1}+c\iff x^n=-x^n\iff 2x^n=0$$

and this is impossible unless $\;x=0\;$ . You now do the other case ($\;n\;$ even), and convince your self that such a function cannot be even.

Comment: @WaldoRozir In general, a sum of an even function and an odd function is neither even nor odd, and by extension arbitrary sums of even functions with odd functions are neither even nor odd.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Thank you, very interesting to know!

Comment: @WaldoRozir note this answer assume $c$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

If $c$ is a constant:

If $n$ is even, then $x^n$ is even, but $x^{n+1}$ is odd. If $n$ is odd, then their opposite.

In no case can they sum to an even function.

$c$ has no effect to your problem, it would only translate the function above $y$.

---

If $c$ is a $c(x)$ function:

If $c$ is a function, namely $c(x)$, it is an uncommon markup, but it is possible. In this case, your example closes out only some specific $c(x)$, you can add any even function to that and the result will be even.

For example, $c(x)=-x^n+\cos(x)$ would do the trick (if $n$ is odd, otherways $c(x)=-x^{n+1}+\cos(x)$ is the solution).

Comment: Ok yes this would do the trick. But that is obvious. I was hoping for an answer where $c$ is **not** of the form $c = -x^n + k$ where $k$ is anything possible. That is why I explicitly wrote about $c$ That is an answer like $x\in \{0\}$ and $n\neq 0$. Does the job, but is not interesting.

Comment: @WaldoRozir $c$ could be of form $-x^{n+1}+k$ as well. Your problem statement wasn't rigorous enough.

Comment: @WaldoRozir Right, also $k$ is a constant which is also an even function.